# how to prevent ssrs hyperlink from getting escaped automatically

Tags: reporting-services

I am using an expression to build a hyperlink on a Textbox Action, I am using special chars like '{,},=', and the problem is that it is getting escaped, how can I prevent it from getting escaped.
I am trying to build the url like

```
https://mysite/transactions/List?filter+{Exchange=USD}
```

but it is getting escaped like

```
https://mysite/transactions/List?filter+%7BExchange=USD%7D
```

as a result, the target page cannot use the filter that I am passing in.